# Copying Plastic Cloud Repo

Tags: plasticscm

Just wondering if this is still the way to copy a cloud repo

Simple repository clone operation
When you're working in distributed mode with a local development server and want to join a project, you have a lot of work ahead with PlasticSCM.

Open PlasticSCM, go to repositories view.
Type in the name of your local plastic server.
Create a new empty repository.
Right-Click and create a workspace from that repository.
Open that workspace.
Go to sync replication view.
Add your local repo as source repository.
Add the repository which holds the project you want to join (clone to your local server) as destination repository.
Click refresh.
Pull the changes.
Open your local workspace.
Click update workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to move a cloud repo to a local server, using the synchronization view is the recommended workflow:
https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide#Chapter23:TheSynchronizationview